# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser

Tags: java, maven, json-simple

I have included json-simple in my pom.xml for Maven:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 3 more
```

Here is my code:

```
JSONObject testLatest = new JSONObject(Files.readString(Paths.get("test-latest.json")));
JSONObject currentServer = new JSONObject(Files.readString(Paths.get("current-server.json")));

String latestStability = testLatest.getJSONObject("response").getString("stability");
String latestMD5 = testLatest.getJSONObject("response").getString("md5");

String currentMD5 = currentServer.getJSONObject("response").getString("md5");

if (latestStability.equals("stable") && !latestMD5.equals(currentMD5)) {
   replaceCurrentServer(true);
   return true;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my module settings in InteliJ:
[image: Screenie]

Comment: Did you add the dependency to your `module-info.java`? To add it just add `requires json.simple;` and leave an empty line underneath.

Comment: I don't have one that I know of, should I create one or is it somewhere I just don't see?

Comment: Normally this file should be in `src/main/java`. IntelliJ should create this file by default. I don't know if Eclipse creates `module-info.java` automatically. For a non-modular project, this file doesn't exist. [See image](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/images/ide/intellij/modular/ide/idea01.png)

Comment: I used the module manager in InteliJ and added it as a runtime dependency on top of it being a compile dependency. It is still not working.

Comment: Can you please add your code and the `module-info.java` to your question?

Comment: No problem, just did.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean the module manager of IntelliJ.

If you add modules to your project you need a **modular project**. Such a project needs a class called `module-info.java`.

According to the [openjfx documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx):

> Add the `module-info` class, including the required modules `javafx.controls` and `javafx.fxml`. Since FXML uses reflection to access the controller in the module, this has to be opened to `javafx.fxml`. Finally, export the package `org.openjfx`.

[See image](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/images/ide/intellij/modular/ide/idea01.png)

In your case the `module-info.java` file should look similar to this *(maybe some differences)*:

```
module com.example.project {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires json.simple;
    requires javafx.graphics;

    opens com.example.project to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.project;
}
```

After that, your code should work.

Comment: I added the module-info.java file given what you sent me (replacing the module name with `net.capbear.serverjarmanager`), and added org.openjfk to my dependencies and plugins in pom.xml, and it still isn't working. Did I do it properly?